# Cyberduck CLI Amazon S3 URL

Tags: amazon-s3, cyberduck

I'm trying to use Cyberduck CLI for uploading/downloading files from Amazon S3 bucket.

But I'm unable to formulate the correct S3 url.
Below is what I've tried so far for listing the bucket contents.

```
C:\>duck --list s3://<bucketname>.s3-<region>.amazonaws.com/<key> --username <access_key> --password <secret_key>
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
Listing directory failed. Java.lang.NullPointerException. 
Please contact your web hosting service provider for assistance.
```

Can you please advise if there is any issue with the s3 URL?

Cyberduck version - 4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/cli#URI) mentions to

> reference the target container (aka bucket) name in the URI like `s3://bucketname/key`.

This means the region specific hostname `s3-<region>.amazonaws.com` can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks David, the `list` command with `s3://bucketname/key` did work over home Wi-Fi but doesn't work on my corporate network. Is there a way to pass proxy details to the CLI command?

Comment: it should pick up proxy settings from Internet Explorer _Tools → Internet Options → Connections tab → LAN Settings_ on Windows.

Comment: Some `Internet Options` tabs are unavailable due to security settings by our org administrator. I can only see `General` and `Privacy` tabs. But using the `NETSH` command I could see that the proxy server is setup as expected. Is the CLI command giving an error due to connection tab being unavailable on IE?